# How to get proper DbSet<Entity> in DbContext when SavingChanges?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, auto-increment, dbcontext

I have a DbContext like

```
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<Entity1> Entities1 { get; set; }
   public DbSet<Entity2> Entities2 { get; set; }
   . . .
}
```

where `Entity1` and `Entity2` inherits base class

```
public abstract class BaseEntity
{
   [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   . . .
}
```

For some reason I needed to remove auto-increment in database and make my custom auto-increment in context in order to avoid database influence. So I decided to estimate current max value in `Id` column and increment it.
I created a simple method

```
private int GetMaxId(IQueryable<BaseEntity> set)
{
   if (set.Count() == 0) return 0;
   else return set.Max(x => x.Id);
}
```

So in context constructor I do folowing:

```
public MyContext() : base("MyConnection")
{
   . . .

   var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
   objectContext.SavingChanges += (sender, args) =>
   {
      foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
      {
         var entity = entry.Entity;
         var state = entry.State;
         if (entity is BaseEntity)
         {
            switch (entry.State)
            {
               case EntityState.Added:
                  var set = Set<entity.GetType()>();
                  (entity as BaseEntity).Id = GetMaxId(set) + 1;
               . . .
            }
         }
      }
      ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
   };

   . . .
}
```

But the thing is I can't construct DbSet like `Set<entity.GetType()>()` as well as `Set<typeof(entity)>()` - it says that last `)` is invalid expression. Although It doesn't depend on amount\order of brackets.
`Set(entity.GetType())` doesn't suit for me too because it returns an untyped DbSet.

Please, tell me how to resolve this problem or what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long struggling with casting of `DbSet` I finally found the solution. The thing is we dont need to cast `DbSet`, we have to cast its elements instead.

That obviously.

Therefore final version of `GetMaxId` (under condition that we checked `entity` is `BaseEntity` before `GetMaxId` invokation) is

```
    private int GetMaxId(DbSet set)
    {
        int max = 0;
        foreach (var item in set)
        {
            int id = (item as BaseEntity).Id;
            if (id > max) max = id;
        }
        return max;
    }
```

and corresponded case is

```
case EntityState.Added:
   (entity as BaseEntity).Id = GetMaxId(Set(entity.GetType())) + 1;
   . . .
```

like @alisabzevari said.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have type determined at runtime as generic type parameter.
In your case, this workaround should work:

```
public MyContext() : base("MyConnection")
{
  var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) this).ObjectContext;
  objectContext.SavingChanges += (sender, args) =>
  {
    foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
    {
      var entity = entry.Entity;
      var state = entry.State;
      if (entity is BaseEntity)
      {
        ProcessEntity((BaseEntity)entity, state);
      }
    }
    ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
  };
}

private void ProcessEntity<T>(T entity, EntityState state) where T : BaseEntity
{
  switch (state)
  {
    case EntityState.Added:
      var set = Set<T>();
      (entity as BaseEntity).Id = GetMaxId(set) + 1;
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understood you meant declaration like `private void ProcessEntity<T>(T entity, EntityState state) where T : class` otherwise it's  an error because `T` in `Set<T>` must be a refference type. So if you write `where T : class` then `set` in `GetMaxId(set)` can't be used as type parameter

Comment: That is correct, it should have been with `where T : class`.
I see your problem with `GetMaxId`. You could add generic constraint on `ProcessEntity` `where T : BaseEntity` instead `T : class`. Then all constraints should be equal.
Sorry for complicating, I don't have VS here so I couldn't try it.

Comment: In this case I cant call `ProcessEntity(entity, state)` because in context constructor `entity` has `object` type and there is no implicit reference conversion

Comment: Yeah, but since you are checking `if(entity is BaseEntity)` you can safely cast it. I finally got my hands on VS. I'm editing my answer with final version which does compile.

Comment: As I answered to @alisabzevari `Cast<BaseEntity>()` compiles, but throws exception during runtime

Comment: Your approach in casting doesnt work as well due to attempting to create `DbSet<BaseEntity>` instead of `DbSet<Entity1>` for instance

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `DbSet` by type of entity using the following code:

```
var set = Set(entity.GetType());
```

Comment: As I said the `Set(TEntity)` is untyped so its inappropriate for me

Comment: Yes, Sorry. Did you tried `var set = Set(entity.GetType()).Cast<BaseEntity>();`?

Comment: Unfortunately it failed. Exception is like "We cant construct DbSet<BaseEntity> based on non-generic objects DbSet for objects of type Entity1". P.S. But nice try! I really hoped it works)